# can't properly match "-" in URI string

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a route system, so that there's a need to receive route variables.
The problem is that it perfectly works, until I have something like `"/post/edit/some-stuff-to-check"` (`"-"` char)

Look at this

```
$pattern = 'post/edit/(\w+)';

$pattern = '/' . str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern) . '/i';

// Note, the "test" is a variable here
$uri = 'post/edit/test';

if (preg_match($pattern, $uri, $params)) {

        // It works, outputs exactly what I need

        // Array ( [0] => post/edit/test [1] => test ) Array ( ) 

        print_r($params);

}
```

But when an uri contains a variable like `/post/edit/foo-bar-test`, it no longer works. So I've tried to match explicitly via regex class, so instead of this:

`$pattern = 'post/edit/(\w+)';`

I used this:

`$pattern = 'post/edit/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]';`

but with no luck.

So the question is, how can I properly match a variable that contains `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` in `URI` string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I used this: `$pattern = 'post/edit/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]';`

The problem with that is, the character set only matches a single character, i.e. you're missing the `+` behind it.

That said, you can also create a character set with `\w` and just add the dash:

```
$pattern = '~post/edit/([\w-]+)~i';
```

In the above pattern, I've used `~` as the expression delimiter; this allows using slashes inside without escaping them.

**Example**

```
$input = '/post/edit/some-stuff-to-check';
$pattern = '~post/edit/([\w-]+)~i';
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => post/edit/some-stuff-to-check
    [1] => some-stuff-to-check
)
```

Comment: Doesn't the `-` inside the capturing group need to be escaped?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi No, if it appears at the start or end of the character class there's no need to escape it.